# SerialComm on windows 10 Vb.net

Tags: vb.net

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.aspx

I have followed a guide from link above to list used COM ports, but nothing is shown when my instrument is plugged in. On the other hand, window 8 and older versions showed correct results. Instrument was plugged into an USB port.

I have been searching internet but unable to identify on how communication with instrument can be handled now. I am looking to create a couple of methods that take data from instrument to save on pc or upload online and to read instrument number.

When I am in the device manager i can see my instrument under "Other devices".

Comment: "Other devices" means that the device wasn't recognized as a serial port, otherwise it would have appeared under "Ports (COM & LPT)". Chances are you don't have the proper driver installed.

Comment: Hi, Yes i've just realised that.. try to install them as we speak :)

Comment: Good :) but IMO this makes this question a lot less coding related, if you encounter problems with the drivers superuser.com is probably the more appropriate place to ask.